# How to display fieldnames beside labels in TYPO3 backend?

Tags: configuration, label, typo3, backend, typo3-9.x

I run a local playground-setup of TYPO3 v9.5 and suddenly from one day to the other the backend displays fieldnames beside the labels (see screenshot), which is super useful!

Now I want to enable this feature in all my TYPO3 installations, but can not find this option (in my playground I install and try out a lot of extensions, so I guess one extension enabled it). Current Application Context is "Production".

[image: Fieldnames beside labels]

Answer (score 4):

This is default behavior for TYPO3 version 9 when in debug mode as an admin user. See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.1/Feature-83461-ShowFieldnameNextToTitleInDebugMode.html

There's also an extension to enable it for TYPO3 8: https://github.com/georgringer/backend_debug

Comment: Thanks you! `['BE']['debug']` is indeed enabled, good to know. The application context was miss-leading me

Answer (score 3):

This feature is [enabled in debug mode only](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.1/Feature-83461-ShowFieldnameNextToTitleInDebugMode.html). Since you should never use debug mode on a live site, you can only have this on a local server or at most at a staging server.